# Setting a typeface to text in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-typeface

I want to set the typeface of the list view into araliya.ttf. Here is my code. There is no error but typeface in listview text is not changed.(It is changed in textviews and buttons) Can someone please tell me what is wrong in here. Thankyou..

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

        private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
        Typeface tf;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, itemList);
            this.itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
            this.itemList.addAll(itemList);
           // tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "araliya.ttf");
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView code;
            CheckBox name;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.symptom_info, null);
                sinfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "araliya.ttf");
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                holder.code.setTypeface(sinfont);
                holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.name.setTypeface(sinfont);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Here is my code in oncreate()

```
dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.symptom_info, itemList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Item item = (Item) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
```

**UPDATE - ISSUE RESOLVED**

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
t1.setTypeface(sinfont);
t1.setText("my,ska m%fNoh f;dard.kak");
```

This works perfectly and change the typeface of the text in textview.

Comment: have you added the typeface .ttf file to assests/fonts ?

Comment: Yes I add that. Typeface is changed in all text views and button text and even spinner text. But it is not changed in the listview. Please help!

Comment: I've added the answer. It's because you haven't set the correct path to font.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that, you haven't set the path right.

```
Typeface sinfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "araliya.ttf");
```

Here *araliya.ttf* is **not the correct path**. It should be *fonts/araliya.ttf*.

Actually the seconds argument inside createFromAsset stands for **path to the font**. So if you have put the font in assets/fonts. Then below is the required code to initialise the font.

```
String path = "fonts/araliya.ttf"
Typeface sinfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), path);
```

Then you could set font using

```
holder.code.setTypeface(sinfont);
```

Comment: I have araliya.ttf inside assets folder.

 TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        t1.setTypeface(sinfont);

        t1.setText("my,ska m%fNoh f;dard.kak");

This works perfectly and change the typeface of the text in textview.

Comment: then try changing it to fonts folder. if still it's not working, then do a test tryout with another font.

Comment: if you have resolved the issue, please update your question with the answer.